# Mail sending when hooking up maligun API with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

As a test, when i access my '/' route I have the relevant controller sending a test email out. However, I am getting this error:

Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/My domain name/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:
Forbidden

Here is my controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $data = [];

    \Mail::send('emails.test', $data, function($message)
   {
        $message->to('my_test_email@gmail.com')->subject('test email');
   });

}
```

I think the issue lies in my setting up of the mailgun API. Here is my .env file where I have set-up my mail.I am unsure if I am using my API key and domain name correctly here.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=port number (which is different to that in the mail.php file)
MAIL_USERNAME=My domain name
MAIL_PASSWORD=My API Key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Here is my mail.php file

```
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'test@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Test'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('My domain name'),
'password' => env('My API Key'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

I also have this in my services.php file

```
  'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'My domain name',
    'secret' => 'My API key',
],
```

My composer.json file

```
   "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `mail.php` you need to change `username` and `password` to:

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

In order to read values from `.env`.

Additionally, `MAILGUN_SECRET` and `MAIL_PASSWORD` are not the same:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'My domain name',
    'secret' => 'My API key', //<-- Here is not the same as MAIL_PASSWORD
],
```

**Note:** The Mail port is **587** (works fine for me) !

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: `MAILGUN_SECRET` and `MAIL_PASSWORD` are not the same. please check the update !

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with my API key